# Git everything up-to-date with pending git commit

Tags: git, github, version-control

I just cloned a repo from an old GitHub project. I made some changes to one file. Successfully staged (`git add -A`) and committed (`git commit -m "my message"`) and then tried to push my changes to master but got an `Everything up-to-date` message from git...

I looked up a bunch of links for a fix but all I could seem to find was some explanation of how `git pull` and `git fetch` works. I have been working with git for a while and have never run into this problem.

[image: git up to date]

Comment: I dont think commit is done, please see if it gives an error after you enter it.

Comment: I left it out, but I can include it if it would help

Comment: Wow, that's dumb.

Comment: I almost always `git add` each individual file I want using `git status` to list everything which has changed.  If you really staged the files, then this shouls not be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot that you posted, it looks like you never ran your commit command.

Otherwise you should run `git add .` and then run `git commit -m "my message"` before you push

Comment: I feel like a noob now. That was the problem. I must not have hit enter after my commit. Weird. Thanks

Comment: No problem, it happens to all of us.  If I helped you answer your question, then feel free to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: in 55 seconds I can

Answer (score 0):

Your staging and commit commands are correct but it seems commit has never happened. Please type `git commit -m "my message"` again and follow if it gives any errors, then `git push` again if successful.